# How to split API response into cells?

Tags: vba, api

I wrote a macro related to API. In response I received something like this:

```
{"name":"NAME","surname":"SURNAME","sex":"MALE","city":"CITY", processingDate":"2018-01-0T11:20:58+00:00"}
```

I would like to put response as NAME, SURNAME, SEX, etc into separate columns in Excel sheet. Now I have this response in one cell. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSON to me so you might want to have a look here [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I need.